# Using pysimplesoap to call ladonize SOAP example. Getting the syntax right

Tags: python, web-services, soap, pysimplesoap, ladon

I'm trying to call the calculator example from 
[ladonize.org](http://ladonize.org/python-demos/) using this code.

I managed to get pysimplesoap to work with other external soap services and am trying to roll out my own soap service using ladon / python 2.7

The SOAP service works when imported into Visual Studio 2008 under Windows.
For python I can't get the syntax for the request right.
The sample web service accepts two numbers a & b and returns the added value as a result

This is the code I have

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient

client = SoapClient(wsdl='http://ladonize.org/python-demos/Calculator/soap/description',
location='http://ladonize.org/python-demos/Calculator/soap/description', cacert=None)

response=client.add(paramters={"a":"1","b":"2"})
print (response)
```

This call is not working.
I get the error "AttributeError: Tag not found: Body (No elements found)"

The call I want to make it is this function

```
    <portType name="CalculatorPortType">
<operation name="add">   
<documentation>Add two integers together and return the result </documentation>
<input message="tns:add"/>
<output
    message="tns:addResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
```

Full description is [here](http://ladonize.org/python-demos/Calculator/soap/description)

Any tips on what to look for in the description to get the syntax right?